# Async and FromAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am working on an c# application and using some Async calls. I have to use an SDK from a given vendor to integrate into the vendors platform. It looks likes the SDK async methods are based on pre 5.0 C# and using the APM model instead of TPM (most of my async work has been with TPM and the await command).

I found the FromAsync method to wrap a APM async method into TPM but having a difficult time with it (hopefully I am on the right path).

The async method in question is called "CommitAsync" and it is from the vendors SDK. When I hover over the method in VS, it outputs this:

```
EditableListConfigurationObject<UserConfiguration.Property>.CommitAsync(System.ComponentMode.AsyncCompletedEventHandler completedCallback, object userState)
```

So I am trying to convert to TPM and so far have this (which is throwing errors):

```
var x = Task.Factory.FromAsync(userConfigurationObject.CommitAsync, UserCreated);
```

UserCreated is my callback function

```
private void UserCreated(Object sender, SystemComponentMode.AsyncCompletedEventArgs args) 
{}
```

When I hover over "userConfigurationOBject.CommitAsync in the FromAsync method, it says "cannot convert from method group to IAsyncResult"

From what I understand, the first parameter in FromAsync is the begin function and the second is the end/complete function. If I am understanding the APM async model correctly and this SDK, I would assume CommitAsync would be the begin function and then its callback would the end function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task.FromAsync` is specifically designed to convert [APM-style asynchronicity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx) into [TAP-style asynchronicity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx). As such, it's inappropriate here.

For a more generalised approach to converting stuff that happens asynchronously into the TAP style, use a [`TaskCompletionSource<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) to do a more "manual" conversion. Approximately, it would go something like this:

```
TaskCompletionSource<SystemComponentMode.AsyncCompletedEventArgs> tcs = 
    new TaskCompletionSource<SystemComponentMode.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>();

EditableListConfigurationObject<UserConfiguration.Property>
    .CommitAsync((sender,args) => {
        tcs.SetResult(args); //or perhaps tcs.SetException in some cases?
    }, object userState);

var resultArgs = await tcs.Task;
```

Personally, I find `Task.FromAsync` to be pretty nasty with all of its overloads. Using a `TaskCompletionSource` is much easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you for this! Used the TaskCompletionSource and all is good. I will do some more research into this to make sure I understand it completely, but for now, this moved me along and proved it can be done!

Answer (score 0):

No, `CommitAsync` simply doesn't follow the APM, given that it doesn't provide what `FromAsync` is expecting.  You can see more about the types of methods it *does* work with in the documentation for `FromAsync.`